# Nginx limit_req_zone ip exceptions

Tags: linux, centos, nginx, centos6

I use:

```
http {
        limit_req_zone  $binary_remote_addr  zone=one:10m   rate=5r/s;
}
server {
    location ~ \.php$ {
            limit_req   zone=one  burst=2 nodelay; 
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
            root   /var/www/;
            fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9001;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include        fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

How can I disable limit for IP: 127.0.0.1 and 99.99.99.99?

Answer (score 6):

```
geo $limited_ip {
    default      1;
    127.0.0.1    0;
    99.99.99.99  0;
}

map $limited_ip $limited_ip_key {
    0 '';
    1 $binary_remote_addr;
}

limit_req_zone $limited_ip_key zone=one:10m rate=5r/s;;
```

- http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_geo_module.html
- http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html